# youcompleteme GoToDefinition command for golang

Tags: vim, go, youcompleteme

I've installed [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/timfeirg/workspace-setup/blob/master/.vimrc#L53) for my vim, alongside `vim-go` and `gocode`, I think I've done every step right but there's no `GoToDefinition` command in vim.

`GoDef` works great, but can ycm goto commands be made available for golang?

Comment: this belongs on their issue tracker not here imo

Comment: YCM currently only supports _canonical_ file structures. You might want to stick with vim-go for a while.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't been reading the docs carefully, it's `:YcmCompleter GoTo`